# Как указать в urlManager что контроллер находитсья в папке controllers/api?

Tags: yii2

```
[
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => ['api/user'],
        'pluralize' => false,
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'GET index' => 'view',
            'PUT index' => 'update',
        ],
```

Данное правило не работает, если перенести UserController в controllers то работает 'controller' => ['user'] но мне нужно чтобы была каталог сontrollers/api.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что вам нужно указать данный контроллер в [Controller Map](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-map)

Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
'components' => [
    //...
],
'controllerMap' => [
    'user' => 'app\controllers\api\UserController',
],
'modules' => [
    //...
],
```